# Smarty with {if} statement to check login

Tags: if-statement, smarty

I'm trying to check the username and password in my script

something like that

```
$username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']);
$password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `db_user` WHERE Username='$username' AND Password='$password'";
$query = mysqli_query($db_handle, $sql) or die ("Error in query: " . mysqli_error($db_handle));

$user_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

mysqli_close($db_handle);


$smarty->assign("DATA", $user_row);
$smarty->assign("USERNAME", $username);
$smarty->assign("PASSWORD", $password);
$smarty->caching=0;
$smarty->display('sign_in.tpl');
```

in .tpl:

```
{if $DATA.Username eq $USERNAME and $DATA.Password eq $PASSWORD}

GOOD

{else}

Bad

{/if}
```

the code is not being applied, and when I send an empty data from the page, I mean not writing any user nor pass, it gives me back "GOOD" message
but when I write anything, no matter if it matches the username and password in the database it still gives me back "BAD" message!!

I've tried to solve this by my own depending on the {debug} function in smarty and here what I've got.

for $DATA: which holds the database information:

```
    Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = Array (10)
  ID => "14"
  Username => "myuser"
  Password => "mypass"
  Name => "me"
  Email => "an email"
  Country => "Russia"
  Activation => "1"
->nocache = false
->scope = "file:sign_in.tpl"
```

Smarty is nice, but it kills me when I stop before somethings I used to do with my eyes closed in usual PHP coding -_-

Comment: **why on earth you do the login validation on the template file?**

Answer (score 0):

It should work without a problem. However assuming that sometimes no record are found (not valid data) you should add extra check to Smarty template:

```
{if $DATA neq null and $DATA.Username eq $USERNAME and $DATA.Password eq $PASSWORD}

    GOOD

{else}

    Bad

{/if}
```

should do the thing. It's working for me. If it doesn't for you, please provide exact data when it's not working for you (`$DATA`, `$USERNAME` and `$PASSWORD` from Smarty debug).

You should also use prepared statements because now your code is vulnerable to MySQL injection